# Error 400 for crud : Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am getting an error 400 for updating a page in yii. I did not change any accessRules()

```
public function accessRules()
{
return array(
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
'actions'=>array('index','view'),
'users'=>array('@'),
    ),
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
'actions'=>array('create','update'),
'users'=>array('@'),
),
array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
'users'=>array('@'),
),
array('deny',  // deny all users
'users'=>array('*'),
),
);
}


public function filters()
{
return array(
'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
);
}
```

I have also enabled the URL formats in urlmanager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'rules'=>array(
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:w+>/<action:w+>/<id:d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<action>'=>'site/<action>'
        ),
    ),
```

I still get error 400 only for one module of mine, and unable to figure it out.

I have added composite primary key to my database long back and missed to check out the functionality of CRUD. I guess the problem is with "composite keys".

Comment: is module enabled in main.php ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your URL when you get the 400? You probably do not send an ID so it can't find the page where it has to be redirected too.

Do you use the standard CRUD update action? Or did you change anything? You could try to dump the $model->id on save to see if it is sent? Something like this:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Model'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Model'];
        if ($model->save())
            // comment the line underneath
            // $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id)); 
            var_dump($model->id);
            die();
    }

    $this->render('update', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Yes its the same thing, my CRUD stopped working when I added a composite key in my model - public function primaryKey() { return array('name','email');}

Comment: do you have the pk's in you database?

Maybe this will help: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/6863-composite-primary-key-not-supported-by-crud-command/

Comment: Yes I have a pk in my db. Later I tried adding composite key using the function but it does not work